# How do I generate the openapi schema for an optional query parameter in utoipa?

Tags: rust, actix-web

New to rust and friends. Using actix-web, utoipa, and utoipa-swagger-ui.

I'm trying to write a basic end point with an optional query parameter. For a minimal example, let's say it's a GET to list objects, with an optional limit parameter. The details don't matter as it's actually the OpenAPI stuff I'm struggling with

```rust
#[derive(Deserialize, ToSchema)]
struct QueryParams {
    limit: Option<bool>
}

#[utoipa::path(get, path="/users", params(("limit", Query))]
#[actix-web::get("/users")]
pub async fn get_users(query_params: web::Query<QueryParams>) -> impl Responder {
  HttResponse::Ok().body("Coming soon")
}
```

I have this endpoint working as is, and if I open the `swagger-ui` page I see the end-point and the query parameters.

But no-matter what I do, I can't get `utoipa` to mark the parameter optional in the generated schema: it is always marked as required.

This seems a fundamental ability, but I can't find any documentation explaining it.

*This may well be a duplicate and, if so, I'm happy to close and delete this question, but I've been fighting with this for a couple of days*

---- Update

Apparently, my example above was too minimal to show the problem. Here is a complete program, which I've cut down from my actual application.

```rust
use actix_web::{get, middleware, post, web, App, HttpResponse, HttpServer, Responder};

use utoipa::OpenApi;
use utoipa_swagger_ui::SwaggerUi;
use serde::Deserialize;
use utoipa::ToSchema;


#[derive(Deserialize, ToSchema)]
struct QFilename {
    filename: Option<String>,
}

#[utoipa::path(get, path = "/v2/users", params(("filename", Query,  description = "download filename")))]
#[get("/users")]
async fn get_users(_query_params: web::Query<QFilename>) -> impl Responder {
    HttpResponse::Ok().body("Hello world!")
}

#[actix_web::main]
async fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    #[derive(OpenApi)]
    #[openapi(paths(
        get_users,
    ))]
    struct OpenApiDoc;

    let openapi = OpenApiDoc::openapi();
    env_logger::init_from_env(env_logger::Env::new().default_filter_or("info"));

    HttpServer::new(move || {
        App::new()
            .wrap(middleware::Logger::default())
            .service(
                web::scope("/v2")
                    .service(get_users),
            )
            .service(
                SwaggerUi::new("/swagger-ui/{_:.*}").url("/api-docs/openapi.json", openapi.clone()),
            )
    })
    .bind(("127.0.0.1", 8080))?
    .run()
    .await
}
```

This is my Cargo.toml

```
[package]
name = "minimal"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
utoipa = { version = "4", features = ["actix_extras"] }
actix-web = "4"
tokio = { version = "1", features = ["full"] }
utoipa-swagger-ui = { version = "6", features = ['actix-web'] }
env_logger = "0.11.2"
log = "0.4.20"
serde = { version = "1", features = ["derive"] }
```

This is the result

[image: Swagger UI screen]

And this is the generated openapi spec

```json
{
   "openapi":"3.0.3",
   "info":{
      "title":"minimal",
      "description":"",
      "license":{
         "name":""
      },
      "version":"0.1.0"
   },
   "paths":{
      "/v2/users":{
         "get":{
            "tags":[
               "crate"
            ],
            "operationId":"get_users",
            "parameters":[
               {
                  "name":"filename",
                  "in":"query",
                  "description":"download filename",
                  "required":true
               }
            ],
            "responses":{
               
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Rust has no `int`.

Comment: true - but that's not the issue. In my code it was something else. This is just a simplified example. I'll change it, but it doesn't affect the question

Comment: Can't reproduce. It shows "nullable: true" for me.

Comment: But the docs say nullable and not-required are different things

Comment: OK - posting a complete, working example.

Comment: Now I can reproduce. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify a type for the parameter.

It should be:

```rust
#[utoipa::path(get, path = "/v2/users", params(("filename" = QFilename, Query, description = "download filename")))]
#[get("/users")]
pub async fn get_users(_query_params: web::Query<QFilename>) -> impl Responder {
    // ...
}

// ...

#[derive(OpenApi)]
#[openapi(paths(get_users), components(schemas(QFilename)))]
struct OpenApiDoc;
```

And then the JSON generated:

```json
{
   "openapi":"3.0.3",
   "info":{
      "title":"my_test",
      "description":"",
      "license":{
         "name":""
      },
      "version":"0.1.0"
   },
   "paths":{
      "/v2/users":{
         "get":{
            "tags":[
               "crate"
            ],
            "operationId":"get_users",
            "parameters":[
               {
                  "name":"filename",
                  "in":"query",
                  "description":"download filename",
                  "required":true,
                  "schema":{
                     "$ref":"#/components/schemas/QFilename"
                  }
               }
            ],
            "responses":{
               
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "components":{
      "schemas":{
         "QFilename":{
            "type":"object",
            "properties":{
               "filename":{
                  "type":"string",
                  "nullable":true
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

This still shows "* required", because the *field `filename`* is optional, but the *object `QFilename`* is required (you never said otherwise). In JSON, (like Swagger's "Try it out" interface), that means we can send an empty object `{}`, but not nothing. In query language, there is no difference, which is why you *expected* it to not say "required".

If you want the parameter to show up as non-required, you can wrap it in `Option`. Not the real parameter - then you'll have double `Option`, but the type you describe to `utoipa`:

```rust
#[utoipa::path(get, path = "/v2/users", params(("filename" = Option<QFilename>, Query, description = "download filename")))]
#[get("/users")]
pub async fn get_users(_query_params: web::Query<QFilename>) -> impl Responder {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this and it makes sense. Now, shouldn't the type for the param be `Option<String>` and not `Option<QFilename>`? I'm thinking of the case where I might have a second, required, query parameter. The examples I've seen would define the field in the same `QFilename` struct.

Comment: Yep, just tried it and the parameter type should match the field type (i.e. Option<string>). Might want to edit the answer to clarify that point. Otherwise, ta muchly.

Comment: @kdopen Well, you can pass `Option<String>`, but you wanted posed struct so this is what I used.

Comment: Yeah, just wanted to be sure I understood the mechanism